# Writing HTTP response to page appears as plaintext

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httpresponse

I am forwarding a request made from a proxy server and rendering the response in the browser. However, when i render the response with `res.write(data)`, it comes up as plaintext instead of rendered html:

```
http.createServer(function targetServer(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    var request = http.request('http://www.google.com', function(res) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            fs.writeFile('res.txt', body, {encoding:'utf8'}, function() {
                util.puts('Success!');

            });
            res.write(body);
        });
    });
    request.end();  
});
```

the contents of `res.txt` are:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title>
<!-- other html -->
</html>
```

but instead of rendering like google.com, it looks like the `res.txt` file:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title>
<!-- other html -->
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After changing the content type to `text/html`, i now get an error in the browser:

```
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

Whats this about?

Comment: Is your second `res` a typo? It seems you are using `response` instead ...

Comment: Nope, see comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
```

And then:

```
response.setEncoding('utf8');
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
});
```

Comment: thanks. Please see the update above, I'm getting an error related to the character encoding on the page.

Comment: `Error: res has no method setEncoding`

Comment: Look at @mscdex's comment.  You have a nested res that probably needs to be renamed to response.

Comment: No, the response object passed into `http.request`'s callback does not have a `write` method. Only the `http.createServer`'s callback does. It seems strange but apparently its how node works.

Comment: Great, that worked. I'm still having issues, but they are not related to this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310708/node-js-proxy-for-monitor-network-requests-and-responses